# Angular CLI and node-gyp : Cannot assign to read only property 'cflags' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, node-gyp

`@angular/cli` has a dependency on node-gyp as you can see here:

```
npm ls node-gyp
apps-backoffice@1.0.0 /home/gabriel/Documents/IdeaProjects/orit.bp.app-leila
└─┬ @angular/cli@17.1.0
  └─┬ pacote@17.0.5
    └─┬ @npmcli/run-script@7.0.3
      └── node-gyp@10.0.1
```

The problem is when I do npm install I get:

```
npm ERR! code 7
npm ERR! path /home/gabriel/.../node_modules/node-zopfli-es
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.6 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'cflags' of object '#<Object>'
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at createConfigFile (/home/gabriel/.../node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:117:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/gabriel/.../node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:84:9
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:191:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 6.5.0-21-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/gabriel/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node" "/home/gabriel/.../node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/gabriel/.../node_modules/node-zopfli-es
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Node-gyp failed to build your package.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update npm and/or node-gyp and if it does not help file an issue with the package author.
```

Reproduction:

`npm install` the following `package.json` using Node `v20.11.0` :

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^20"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.1702.1",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~17.2.1",
    "@angular/animations": "~17.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "~17.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~17.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~17.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "~17.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~17.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "~17.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~17.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~17.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~17.2.3",
    "@elastic/ecs-winston-format": "~1.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "~4.5.3",
    "compression": "~1.7.4",
    "connect-redis": "^6.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.6",
    "d3": "^6.7.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.25",
    "got": "^11.8.2",
    "iban": "0.0.14",
    "ioredis": "^4.27.11",
    "jsonwebtoken": "~9.0.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "ngx-currency": "^17.0.0",
    "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "shrink-ray-current": "^4.1.3",
    "simple-oauth2": "^3.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "zone.js": "0.14.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@dotenvx/dotenvx": "^0.19.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "~17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~17.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~17.2.3",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.2",
    "@types/connect-redis": "0.0.17",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/d3": "^6.7.8",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.10",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.7",
    "@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.30",
    "@types/iban": "0.0.35",
    "@types/ioredis": "^4.27.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.13",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.9",
    "@types/node": "18.19.19",
    "@types/pluralize": "0.0.33",
    "@types/prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "@types/simple-oauth2": "^2.5.8",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.16",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.62.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.50.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "4.6.0",
    "karma": "6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "lint-staged": "^11.2.6",
    "ng-mocks": "^14.2.0",
    "nock": "^13.1.3",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "supertest": "^6.3.4",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "10.9.2",
    "typescript": "5.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model: Dell Inc. Precision 5560

Memory: 64,0 GiB

Processor: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-11850H × 16

Graphics: Intel® UHD Graphics (TGL GT1)

Disk Capacity: 1,0 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version: 1.26.0

OS Name: Ubuntu 23.10

OS Type: 64-bit

GNOME Version: 45.2

Windowing System: X11

Kernel Version: Linux 6.5.0-21-generic

Comment: By the way I asked this in github issues first but Angular Collaborator told me to come here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/27191#event-11995473090

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was related to this dependency which seems to be abandoned: https://www.npmjs.com/package/shrink-ray-current . Removing solves the issue while doing `npm install` and it was not related to Angular CLI at all :)